# How to make Excel with zero before the number in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, excel

I make from my program an excel file (xls or csv).

I send `00123`  and in Excel I see `123`

How I can send and see `00123`

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm happy to see you're always thanking us in advance - nice and polite. Just as a note: when you do, please use the proper spelling of "Thanks in advance" - there's no apostrophe in that phrase......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because excel is treating the data as 'numeric'. A simple way to force Excel to accept anything as text is to prepend an apostrophe to the text.

e.g. to write an integer 123 as 00000123 just write:

```
ActiveCell = "'" & Format(123, "00000000")
```

EDIT: Another solution is to set the Cells **NumberFormatProperty** to text:

```
Worksheet.GetRange(..).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "@"
```

You might want to see this article: [Excel Cell Auto Format](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet1218.htm)

Answer (score 2):

In C# to see the CSV with the padding use

```
myVar.PadLeft(5,'0')
```

In Excel set the number format to custom 00000 or ZipCode

Comment: thanks for the help, but it was only a sample there will be 000000000123 or 0123 - i dont know how many zeros will be

Comment: So how do you know how many you want to see? based on the biggest number?

Comment: what i send - this what i want to see

Comment: LOL, that's going to be the useless spreadsheet in the world.  Why don't you create a Word document instead?